# How do I update a statement of Data of UnsafePointer for Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers

I'm getting the error below for this statement:

```
 let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(cubeData), count: cubeData.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
```

cubeData is defined as:  `var cubeData = [Float](repeating: 0, count: size * size * size * 4)`

Error:

```
 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: So `cubeData` is a `[Float]`?

Comment: Oops. I've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.withUnsafeBufferPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1540400-withunsafebufferpointer) to obtain a buffer pointer (i.e. a pointer to an array with its length). Then use [`Data.init(buffer:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779609-init) to initiate the data from a buffer pointer.

```
let cubeData: [Float] = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]

let b = cubeData.withUnsafeBufferPointer { Data(buffer: $0) }

print(b as NSData)
// <cdcc8c3f cdcc0c40 33335340 cdcc8c40>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your fast response.